# Django: Change pagination style

Tags: pagination, django-2.0

I am using pagination on my view by adding `paginate_by` something like this:

```
class ProductView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "product_table.html"
    paginate_by = PAGE_SIZE
```

It generates a paging element that appears as follows on the page:
[image]

I want to customize this paging element to make it more useful. Maybe something more like this:
[image]

How do I override the default paging style?

Answer (score 0):

This [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/pagination/) has the code to get the page_obj into the context. It also shows how to use the has_next property, so you would use that to see if there are a few more pages to show. Alternatively, you could just simplify your html and calculate # pages len(object_list)/PAGE_SIZE and then pass the list of page links in the context.